# UIButton setText programmatically

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have about 10 UIButtons on xib file and want to setText programmatically

Answer (score 62):

You might want to be more specific next time you ask a question.

You can try assign a different tag for each button in interface builder (or the same tag if thats what you need) and then use the following code

```
for (int i = 1 ; i<=10;i++)
{
     UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[myView viewWithTag:i];
     [myButton setTitle:@"my text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for... one question myview would be instance of xib file?

Comment: I assume your NIB is for a UIViewController, so if this code is inside the UIViewController code myView should be view

Comment: or more precisely, myView must be the parent view of your buttons

Comment: Anybody have thoughts on whether it's better to do this or just make some instance variables with IBOutlets from IB?

Comment: It really depends what are you after. If all the buttons have different names and functions, then IBOutlets might be the right way to go.

Comment: @bjtitus the better is to use an Outlet Collection, check my answer

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3+:

```
button.setTitle("Button Title", for: .normal)
```

Otherwise:

```
button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you could create a collection of buttons from your layout:

Select the first button from your xib and drag it with the right button into your code:
[image: Drag firs button]

then you should select "Outlet Collection" for the Connection type and assign a name:

[image: select Outlet collection]

Then in your code you have an array of buttons from your xib file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Next select and drag the other buttons over the created collection, do it one by one in the order you want to iterate them:
[image: Drag the other buttons]

You can check the order of the buttons in the connections inspector hovering over the array you have created:
[image: check button order]

Now set each button text:

```
for (int i = 0; i<self.buttons.count; i++) {
    UIButton * button = self.buttons[i];
    [button setTitle: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %d",i ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Note that UIControlStateNormal is the default state and if not overridden it will be shown for all states:

> In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the UIControlStateNormal value. If the value for UIControlStateNormal is not set, then the property defaults to a system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state.

I hope that helps